# VB.NET - Getting value from MySQL database and inserting it into Ms. Access (MDB) database

Tags: vb.net

I want to Export database from MySQL and import it to Ms. Access (MDB) database. I've tried to code a long LoC to process importing database into a DataTable variable and store the value into it.

This is my code for getting value from adm_users database on MySQL

```
a_query = "SELECT * FROM adm_users where uac_code='4' or uac_code='4A' or uac_code='1'"
a_da = New MySqlDataAdapter(a_query, db_conn)
a_da.Fill(a_ds, "adm_users")
a_dt = a_ds.Tables("adm_users")
```

and then i want to store **a_dt** value into MDB database with this code

```
For x = 0 To a_dt.Rows.Count - 1
    b_query = "INSERT INTO user_login
               (userid, username, password, uac) VALUES
               ('" + a_dt.Rows(x).Item("userid") + "', '" + a_dt.Rows(x).Item("username") + "', '" + a_dt.Rows(x).Item("userpwd") + "', '2')"
    b_sql = New OleDbCommand(b_query, ms_conn)
    b_sql.ExecuteReader()
Next
```

and then trying to find a string queries stored in **b_query**, it looks like this

```
INSERT INTO user_login
                (userid, username, password, uac) VALUES
                ('admin', 'Varenicou', 'administrator', '2')
```

and then the return value is: "syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"
i found there's nothing wrong with the queries, so i replace **b_query** variable with simple query like "SELECT FROM user_login" and the return value is: "syntax error in SELECT * FROM statement"

maybe i'm too dumb to ask this question, but my opinion is that VB.NET thinks that i've already opened a connection to MySQL Database and must always on MySQL database. So, when i open database connection with Ms. Access it'll return value like that and VB.NET confused with "which database you wanna use?"

any idea for me to do this task? i've asked my friend for some suggestions, he said that i need to work with class, i also have another idea to work with another new project that doing this task for inputing into Ms. Access database by exporting MySQL database into CSV first.

Comment: Ha a look at parameterising your insert statement, string concatenations like that always cause headaches.  Also check the values you're inserting.  You might find special characters in there.  A miss-placed ' might be what's causing your problem

Comment: i have tried using that queries to Ms. Access's Query Design. And it works perfectly and i got the value i want.

Comment: But what about the data you're getting out of MySQL, Does that have any special characters in it?  Is any of that data being inserted in to your mdb or is the error happening on the first loop iteration?

Comment: there's nothing like any special characters on it, i add ' ' to the values because it's a "varchar" data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Having reread your question, I can tell you that the specific issue you're having is due to the fact that "password" is a reserved word in Jet/Access SQL. Any time you want to use a reserved word as an identifier in SQL, you need to escape it.  For Access, you do that by wrapping it in brackets, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO user_login (userid, username, [password], uac)
VALUES (@userid, @username, @password, @uac)
```

My original advice below still stands though.

**ORIGINAL:**

If you have a `DataTable` then you don't loop through it to save the data. Just as you make a single `Fill` call on a data adapter to retrieve data, so you make a single `Update` call to save data. How does it make sense to call `ExecuteReader` when there's nothing to read? At least call `ExecuteNonQuery` but even that is not ideal.

If you want to insert the data it contains then you have to configure the `InsertCommand` of the second data adapter. You also need all the `DataRows` in the `DataTable` to have a `RowState` of `Added`. To do that, you simply set `AcceptChangesDuringFill` to `False` on the first data adapter.  When you call `Fill`, it adds all the rows and thus their `RowState` is `Added`.  It then calls `AcceptChanges`, which sets all the `RowStates` to `Unchanged`.  Tell it not to call `AcceptChanges` and you're ready to insert.

Here's an example of getting data from one database and inserting into another using two data adapters:

```
Dim table As New DataTable

Using sourceAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM MyTable",
                                            "source connection string here") With {.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False}
    sourceAdapter.Fill(table)
End Using

Using destinationConnection As New OleDbConnection("destination connection string here"),
      destinationCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2)",
                                             destinationConnection),
      destinationAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter With {.InsertCommand = destinationCommand}
    With destinationCommand.Parameters
        .Add("@Column1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "Column1")
        .Add("@Column2", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Column2")
    End With

    destinationAdapter.Update(table)
End Using
```

As you can see, it's fairly simple stuff.  One data adapter with a `SelectCommand` and another with an `InsertCommand`.  There's nothing special about the adding of the parameters, but you do need to know about parameters in the first place.  If you don't know how to use parameters with ADO.NET then you should learn immediately.  You can find my own explanation [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).

Comment: but, with this i can't call to my own Connection Module that i've already initiated right?

Comment: What do you mean by "connection module"? If you just mean a module that creates a connection object then of course you can. What I provided was an EXAMPLE. It simply demonstrates a principle. You can adapt it any way you like to fit your specific needs. If you already have a connection object then you pass that to the data adapter constructor. If you mean that you have a proper data access layer then it should already support this type of functionality or it's not a proper DAL. If you have a DAL that loops through `DataTables` and doesn't use parameters then it's garbage that needs fixing.

Comment: your edited answer is the actual answer for my problem. Thanks anyway.